# Usage of "to make something out of something"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I wrote:

> It (the software) divides the page into some slides and makes a video out of them.

Is it a correct usage of "out of"? as I searched **[out of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+out+of+nothing)** means to create something of value from nearly worthless parts. Can I use **from** here?

Comment: The page you've hyperlinked says "make something out of **nothing**". In your case, you're making something out of **something**.

Comment: *Out of* usually refers to physically assembling parts or materials into a whole: "This table is made out of wood", "This machine is made out of old car parts". When speaking about software, the input is typically preserved, so this meaning becomes figurative.

Answer (score 5):

> "It (the software) divides the page into slides and makes a video out of them."

This is correct. Please note that I have removed the word "some," which isn't necessary.

You can also write:

> "It (the software) divides the page into slides and makes a video from them.

This is also correct, so you are right!

You did a good job constructing the statement and asking about the use of "from" as an alternative to "out of." Of the two, the first example is the most clear and immediately understandable ***to me***, but both are correct and would work well for you. Developing skill in writing clear descriptions of software is an excellent practice, as much that is written is difficult for ordinary people like me to understand.

Comment: There is no difference or preference between them?

Comment: @Ahmad- My preference is for the first example: "It divides the page into slides and makes a video out of them." Of the two correct ways of stating what the software does, this is the most clear to me. I apologize for not including my preference in the answer.

Comment: @Ahmad- I have edited my answer to include my preference for the first example. Thank you for the suggestion, kind sir.